# distanceFromLocation seems not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, location, cllocationmanager

In an app I need to calculate the distance between two point. I'm doing it like this.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    NSLog(@"updating");
     //Getting my concerts
    arrConcerten = [matches mutableCopy];

       for (Event *concert in arrConcerten) {
            CLLocation *restaurnatLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[concert.eve_latitude floatValue] longitude:[concert.eve_longitude floatValue]];

            CLLocationDistance meters = [restaurnatLoc distanceFromLocation:newLocation];
            NSLog(@"meters are %f",meters);
            if(meters > 5000){
                [locationManager2 stopUpdatingLocation];
                NSString *message2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Long = %f and lat= %f and Concert Lat = %f and long = %f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude,newLocation.coordinate.latitude,[concert.eve_latitude floatValue],[concert.eve_longitude floatValue]];
                NSLog(@"%@",message2);
            }else{

                NSLog(@"too far away");
            }

        }
    }
```

This is what my log says.

```
2013-10-17 15:57:23.518 Domino[7468:907] meters are 7973.753294
2013-10-17 15:57:23.520 Domino[7468:907] Long = 5.621456 and lat= 51.097340 and Concert Lat = 51.038139 and long = 5.557330
2013-10-17 15:57:23.896 Domino[7468:907] meters are 27850.874245
2013-10-17 15:57:23.899 Domino[7468:907] Long = 5.621456 and lat= 51.097340 and Concert Lat = 50.860332 and long = 5.493722
```

Like you can see, the locations are near each other. but it still says that we are too far away. Can somebody help me ?

Comment: It does not look like they're near each other to me, why do you say so?

Comment: Perhaps `if(meters > 5000)` should be `if(meters <= 5000)` ?

Comment: Have you tried treating the concert lat & long as doubles instead of float? float would truncate the value, which might be causing the issue you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using this:

if it s over 5000 meter: do something, else too far away? I don't understand the logic. If its too far away it's over 5000 meter. So I think:

```
  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
               fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
        NSLog(@"updating");
         //Getting my concerts
        arrConcerten = [matches mutableCopy];

       for (Event *concert in arrConcerten) {
            CLLocation *restaurnatLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[concert.eve_latitude floatValue] longitude:[concert.eve_longitude floatValue]];

            CLLocationDistance meters = [restaurnatLoc distanceFromLocation:newLocation];
            NSLog(@"meters are %f",meters);
            if(meters <= 5000){
                [locationManager2 stopUpdatingLocation];
                NSString *message2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Long = %f and lat= %f and Concert Lat = %f and long = %f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude,newLocation.coordinate.latitude,[concert.eve_latitude floatValue],[concert.eve_longitude floatValue]];
                NSLog(@"%@",message2);
            }else{

                NSLog(@"too far away");
            }

        }
    }
```

or of corse:

```
if(meters > 5000){

                    NSLog(@"it's far enough");
 }else{

                    NSLog(@"too close");
 }
```

And there is a really important thing:

> This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing
>   a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth. The
>   resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account
>   specific altitude changes between the two locations.
>   from [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation%3a)

distanceFromLocation measure the distance "in the air", not a turn by turn measure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution-

```
-(NSString *)getDistance:(NSDictionary *)dicVal{
    CLLocation *pinLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[dicVal valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue] longitude:[[dicVal valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]];

    CLLocation *userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:appDelegate.userLocation.latitude longitude:appDelegate.userLocation.longitude];

    CLLocationDistance distance = [pinLocation distanceFromLocation:userLocation];
    NSString *dist=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%4.0f %@", distance/1000,NSLocalizedString(@"KM", nil)];
    return dist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its just issue of allocation you have to allocate every time `cllocation` manager like as below:

```
LocationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
LocationManager.delegate = self;
LocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
LocationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
[LocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
CLLocation *location = [LocationManager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate1 = [location coordinate];


CLLocation *currentLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coordinate1.latitude longitude:coordinate1.longitude];
CLLocation *restaurnatLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:l@"Your latitude not current" longitude:@"Your longitude not current'];
CLLocationDistance meters = [restaurnatLoc distanceFromLocation:currentLoc];    


if (meters > 1000)
{
    Distancelbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"You are Away %.2f Km",meters];
}
else{
    Distancelbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"You are Away %.2f Mtr",meters];
}
```

`